# Creating multiringbuffer with flat ends using QGIS

Tags: qgis, buffer

In the QGIS-Buffer, you have the option to chose the flat end, by specifying it in the 'End cap style' as you can see in the image:

[image]

However, in the MultiRingBuffer tool it seems as if there is no such option.

Is it possible to create a multiringbuffer with flat ends using QGIS?

Comment: Workaround: as all processing QGIS tools, you can right-click on it in the processing toolbox and choose to batch the tool, then use the buffer tool to create one buffer per line with flat end.

Comment: Thank you, I just tried it out, and yes, it does work as a work around!